# iPhone 6+ does not have navigation bar back button item

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have developed an app in Xcode 5 before the new versions of iOS and iPhone 6/6+. It was working well in Xcode 5 with its simulators (iPhone retina 4 inches, etc.) but now that I have updated to Xcode 6 and I run my app in new simulators, it works great in the iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, and 6 simulators but not in the iPhone 6+ simulator.

I have a table view in my first view controller. If you tap on a cell the push segue brings you to an another view controller. There are two problems:

1. In every view controller, the top of the object (e.g. table view or a UIImage) is not shown and the scene is deficient.
2. when we go to the second view controller there is no back button item on the top in order to return to the home view controller.

How can I fix this? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a bug in the iPhone 6+ simulator - I have also observed a similar behavior, but only on the simulator. Running the app on a real iPhone 6+ works as expected - the navigation bar is there as are all the buttons.

Comment: So, do you mean that I have to buy an iPhone 6+ to assure that my app runs as expected? How can I run my app on a real device? because I heard that I have to register for a MAC certificate and there are several steps to run an app on a real iPhone, isn't it?

Comment: That's right. To run an application on a real device, you have to be registered for the Apple Developer Program and pay $99 (the tax per year). I would advice you to file a radar (bug report) to Apple. Additionally I think they should provide an update for Xcode soon, which might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its because iPhone 6+ simulator screen is too big to fit in some mac screen.
In a view controller the top object is not cut off, just use mouse scroller to scroll up to see the top object.
In second view controller again use mouse scroller to see back button.